# Indefinite integral including cos

Tags: indefinite-integrals

Does anyone have a solution to the following indefinite integral?

$$
F(x)=\frac{1}{4}  \int (1-[1-\cos\phi_1-\cos\phi_2]^2) \, dx 
$$
where
$$
\tan\phi_1=\frac{k_1}{x} \  ,   \    \tan\phi_2=\frac{k_2}{k_3-x}
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Note that since tan = opp/adj, it follows that if $\tan\theta =A/B$, then $\sin\theta=\frac{\pm A}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$ and $\cos\theta =\frac{\pm B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$. The signs $\pm$ are the same but ambiguous because $\frac{A}{B}=\frac{-A}{-B}$.